# Why I get more timeout result when using .NET Ping than WebResponse?

Tags: .net, http, network-programming, icmp

The network is like below.

1. Server1: Windows Server 2012 R2 with IIS
2. Server2: Windows Server 2012 R2 with IIS
3. Load Balancer connecting with Server1 and Server2
4. Clients: 2,000 PCs with Windows 7.

There is a online/offline checking method in my application at client and run every minute.

At first, my application at client is checking online/offline by request a web page by .NET WebResponse Class with 30 seconds timeout. The destination IP is load balancer. Between the client working time (9:00~21:00), I got only about 2~10 times timeout result when running the checking online/offline method.

Then, I think the traffic of WebResponse is bigger than Ping, so I changed the method to use System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping instead of WebResponse. The timeout is also 30 seconds and the destination IP is load balancer as well. But the problem is, Between the client working time (9:00~21:00), I got about 50~100 times timeout result when running the checking online/offline method.

I cannot figure out why the Ping get more timeout result than WebResponse?
It is better to use WebResponse to checking online/offline than Ping?

Answer (score 0):

> It is better to use WebResponse to checking online/offline than Ping?

If you're trying to evaluate wether the web application is responding, you need to use WebResponse. The only thing the Ping tool is going to tell you is wether the load balancer's interface is responding.

As for your irregular results, it may be that you're losing the same amount of traffic but because WebResponse is IP and ping is ICMP the WebResponse is compensating for poor connections.

You mention that you have 2000 clients and that this problem is occurring during business hours. Is it possible that this check itself is causing your issues? If all of your clients start sending this check when everyone uses it perhaps you're causing an unnecessary load on the application?

Comment: Thank you for your advise. I didn't know that the WebResponse is compensating for poor connections. Could you please tell me more about this?
It's possbile that all of 2,000 clients start sending this check at the same time, so I need a reliable  online check method for this situation. The WebResponse is really a good option if it is compensating for poor connections.